# While loop isn't looping

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a while loop which I would like to keep prompting a user to enter a number until the user types "exit". Unfortunately when the user enters anything, they aren't prompted to enter another number, and the procedure doesn't end. I'm using Pycharm as my IDE. Here is my code:

```
a = []
num = ""
newa = []
def makelist():
    num = input("Type a number! Or if you want to exit, type 'exit' ")
    while num != "exit":
        if int(num):
            a.append(num)
        num
def firstandlast():
    newa.append(a[0]) and newa.append([len(a)])
    print("Here are the first and last numbers you typed:")
    print(newa)
makelist()
firstandlast()
```

Comment: You never ask for `input()` again after the first time.

Comment: `newa.append(a[0]) and newa.append([len(a)])` will only append `a[0]`.  `append` returns `None` and `and` is short-circuited so whatever is after `and` is not even evaluated. Also, `a[-1]` is the last element in `a`, not `[len(a)]`.

Comment: What is the `num` doing on the last line of `makelist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's better to use `isdigit()` as a function to determine whether the input is number or not. So this part would be like below:

```py
if num.isdigit():
     a.append(num)
```

And to get new input in each level of loop you can add an additional `input()` into your loop:

```py
while num != "exit":
     if num.isdigit():
          a.append(num)
     num = input()
```

And you were adding your first and last number in one line using `and`. I edited it into two line which works fine right now.And by the way you can achieve the last element of an array using `-1`. So `a[-1]` will give you the last item. The `firstandlast` function would be like this:

```py
def firstandlast():
    newa.append(a[0])
    newa.append(a[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `makelist` function to:

```
def makelist():
    num = input("Type a number! Or if you want to exit, type 'exit' ")
    while num != "exit":
        if int(num):
            a.append(num)
        num = input("Type a number! Or if you want to exit, type 'exit' ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to assign `num` again in the while loop to be equal to the input again:

```
while num != "exit":
    num = input("Type a number! Or if you want to exit, type 'exit' ")
```